# Highlight.js svg tag

Tags: javascript, svg, compilation, highlight.js

How does one add an svg tag to a `<code>` block with highlight.js?

Even when setting the lang to html, `SVG` tags are compiled into page elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`code` is a *phrase tag* and does not natively escape the HTML tags. It's not intended to share code using tags inside of it: you have to escape them before. You can easily achieve it by replacing > and < symbols with `&gt;` and `&lt;` before inserting them in the `code` tag. Highlight.js does nothing more than coloring syntax.